# Laravel Model->save() returns false but no error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Normally when I call `Model->save()`, it creates the new record in the database successfully. I'm trying to debug a situation when nothing happens and `Model->save()` returns false. How do I find out what's happening?

```
$user = new User;
$user->fields = 'example';
$user->save(); // returns false
```

Running this does not show any insert queries.

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

But if I `var_dump($user)`, I correctly get all the fields properly saved in the object.

Thanks!

Comment: `Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time) {
 error_log($query);
});` try this to check the query.

Comment: Do you mean get know when the update error?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To get the insert queries when `$user->save();` error, you can try to catch the exception like this:

```
    try{
       $user = new User;
       $user->fields = 'example';
       $user->save(); // returns false
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
       // do task when error
       echo $e->getMessage();   // insert query
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It should really be `(\Exception $e)` because otherwise it will think you are looking for the Exception class in this namespace. (Unless you write `use Exeption`)

Comment: This code will never execute what's within the catch block, since the `save()` method returns false, therefore it does not trigger an exception.

Comment: also `save()` throws a PDOException

Comment: **it should NEVER be  echo $e->getMessage();** Doing this is just barbaric. Laravel can handle exceptions already, no need for such ugly try catch with echo.

Comment: Weird answer and comments. Does Laravel swallow the exception to return false if not caught?

Comment: This does not work, save returns 1 but no exception is thrown

Comment: Does this really work by catching exceptions?

Comment: Got about a hundred Exceptions in the libraries. which one to use?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's already answered, but in case someone else needs a different approach, I was able to see the $model->save() error with the underappreciated component of Laravel: tinker

```
php artisan tinker
$old = \App\Model\User::find(1);
$new = $old->replicate();
$new->save();
```

Then I was able to see the error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relations' in 'field list'
> (SQL: insert into `temp_users` (...