# My laravel try-catch statements doesn't work

Tags: laravel, try-catch

Here I have a simple laravel code in post controller that store a post. I want to have unique titles. So I set title in database as unique. In below code I have a try-catch statement. But when I create a post with duplicate title I take error (**laravel error page shown** ) and catch doesn't call! I don't know why and I confused a little. Can anybody help me please?

```
    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'category_id' => $request->category
    ]);
    try {
        $post->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'New post created successfully.');
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        Session::flash('success', $e->getMessage());
    } 
return redirect()->route('post.index');
```

The laravel error page say:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'T3' for key
>   'posts_title_unique' (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`,
>   `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (T3, kj;k, ,
>   2018-12-20 19:53:52, 2018-12-20 19:53:52))

What I want is to show this error to user. So I used try-catch statement. But it seems does't work correctly.
In this link seems try-catch should work: [Laravel Model->save() returns false but no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759978/laravel-model-save-returns-false-but-no-error) . Also I use catch for mange other errors maybe happen

Comment: Try to use `dd($request->all());` to see what comes in the request to see if it is all correct. And what does the laravel error page says?

Comment: @Brunaine The laravel error page say: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'T3' for key 'posts_title_unique' (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (T3, kj;k, , 2018-12-20 19:53:52, 2018-12-20 19:53:52))`

Comment: You have already a Title created with that name `T3`

Comment: @Brunaine Yes. And I want to show this error message to user. so I use try-catch.

Comment: Oh okay I'm sorry I miss understood, just give a try and instead of a try catch just use a `if( !$post->save() ) { // didn't save } `  and  `if( $post->save() ) { // did save }`

Comment: @Brunaine Thanks for your opinion. In this link seems try-catch should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759978/laravel-model-save-returns-false-but-no-error

Comment: @Brunaine Also I use catch for mange other errors maybe happen.

Comment: You can also try to catch `Throwable`. Look at this comment on php.net [Errors in PHP 7 ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php#119652)

Comment: The thing with the try catch is always saving to the `laravel.log` which with a lot of errors can take up some space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Post::create()` outside the `try-catch` block. The `create()` function will not only create a model instance within memory, but also call `save()` on the newly created instance, making your explicit call to `save()` redundant.

What you actually want is to use `new Post(...)` or `Post::create(...)` within the `try-catch` block instead:

```
try {
    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'category_id' => $request->category
    ]);
    Session::flash('success', 'New post created successfully.');
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    Session::flash('success', $e->getMessage());
} 
return redirect()->route('post.index');
```